# How to change theme programmatically for specific controller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

In magento 1.X we can change theme programmatically in controller action by below code :

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
    ->setPackageName('packagename') //Name of Package
    ->setTheme('default');// Name of theme
```

**How to change theme programmatically for specific controller in magento 2 ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging the code I found the solution.

Write below code at the starting  of your controller's action execute function's body.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::class)->setDesignTheme('Magento/luma', 'frontend');
```

For example :

```
public function execute()
    {

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::class)->setDesignTheme('Magento/luma', 'frontend');

        $post = $this->initModel();

        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found'));
            die;
        }

        /* @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'blog_page_render',
            ['post' => $post, 'controller_action' => $this]
        );

        return $resultPage;
    }
```

In `setDesignTheme` pass your theme's name and area (frontend|adminhtml) as :

```
$objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::class)->setDesignTheme('Theme_Name', 'Area');
```

Hope this will help others :)

Comment: i used this code but css and js no loading have you done those also if done can you pls tell me

Comment: run following commands :

Comment: which commands your saying

Comment: rm -rf pub/static/*                            /*to remove files excluding .htaccess*/

rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*                 /*to remove files excluding .htaccess*/

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --theme Vendor/theme

Comment: I did these already and files are created in pub/static but not showing in frontend.you did right that time you got all files loaded ? 
$objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface::class)->setDesignTheme('Infortis/pawan', 'frontend');

Comment: I my case it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am changing theme through phtml file

Answer (score 0):

See `vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php`

It uses: `$this->_getDesign()->setArea($this->_code)->setDesignTheme($theme);`

and

```
            $this->_design->loadChange(
                $this->_scopeResolver->getScope()->getId()
            )->changeDesign(
                $this->_getDesign()
            );
```

`loadChange` and `changeDesign` are defined in `vendor/magento/module-theme/Model/Design.php`

```
/**
 * Apply design change from self data into specified design package instance
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $packageInto
 * @return $this
 */
public function changeDesign(\Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface $packageInto)
{
    $design = $this->getDesign();
    if ($design) {
        $packageInto->setDesignTheme($design);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set theme for specific website in controller then use below code in your controller file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$config = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Theme\Model\Config"); 
$storeManager  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

//I have used default luma theme ID, You can change it based on theme.
$themeId = 2; 
$theme = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Theme\Model\ThemeFactory")->create()->load($themeId);

$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
if ($theme->getId()) {
    $config->assignToStore($theme,[$websiteId],'website');
}
```

Thanks.